# Yii2, файл вне web, скачать его

Tags: php, yii2, apache2

В проекте на Yii2, я загружаю через форму файлы в папку files, находящуюся в корне проекта, а не в папке `web`.

Как вывести ссылки на эти файлы в view, чтобы их можно было скачивать, как-то динамически?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня нет под рукой ни php, ни Yii2, поэтому ограничусь подсказками, а  не готовым решением из разряда "скопируй и выполни".

Вам нужен некий контролер, назовем его `FilesController`:

```php
class FilesController extends Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Внутри него будут два action'а - `actionIndex` и `actionDownload`. Первый будет служить для показа списка файлов, а второй для непосредственной выдачи содержимого файла пользователю.

Так же нам понадобится некое свойство, которое будет содержать путь к папке с файлами. В Yii2 путь к корневой папке находится в `Yii::$app->basePath`. Соответственно, пишем в методе инициализации контролера:

```php
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $path;

public function init()
{
    $this->path = realpath(Yii::$app->basePath . '/files/');
}
```

В `actionIndex` получаем список файлов и передаём его в view:

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $files = array();

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($this->path) as $item) {
        array_push($files, $item->getFilename());
    }

    return $this->render('files', array(
        'files' => $files
    ));
}
```

В view вам нужно будет вывести список ссылок указывающих на `actionDownload`. Url для каждого файла можно получить примерно так:

```php
Url::to(['download','name'=> $fileName]);
```

Ну и собственно в `actionDownload` отдаём файл(для `$name` желательно добавить валидацию, что бы пользователи не присылали всякую ересь):

```php
public function actionDownload($name)
{
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($this->path .  $name);
}
```

Comment: спасибо! с Yii совсем недавно работаю и ваш ответ помог не только с этим вопросом

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял вопрос, вы загружаете файлы - ресурсы для пользователей сайты(документы, картинки ит.д.). То вам следует их загружать в папку web - чтобы они были доступны для просмотра и скачивания. Папка assets - нужна для ресурсов относящихся к frontend части сайта(скрипты, стили, иконки и т.д.)

Comment: а если это файлы важные и нужно сделать так чтобы они не были доступны не зарегистрированным пользователям и по прямой ссылке? Как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: Отдавать файлы не по прямой ссылке, а через действие контроллера, которое будет проверять залогиненность пользователя и отдавать ему страницу скачивания. То есть, вместо ссылки на файл, делаем ссылку на страницу загрузки, генерим персональную ссылку и т.п. Таким образом, страница скачивания будет у всех одинаковой, а вот содержимое - разным.

Comment: @Rumato а вам не кажется? что это надо было писать в вопросе, как был поставлен вопрос, такой вы ответ и получили. А тут начинаете минусовать. А вообще все вам правильно сказал qtm. Но по факту вы с таким же успехом можете положить файл в директорию web, генерить рандомную ссылку и экшеном отдавать файл.

Comment: @Reinq, я вам нисколько не минусовал, это был не я и я благодарен любой помощи

Comment: @Rumato извините был не прав.

Answer (score 0):

https://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/

Можно просто сообщить nginx что бы он отдал файл из закрытой директории.

```
function file_force_download($file) {
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $file);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

В Yii из коробки есть только два варианта - файлы видны (папка web) и файлы не видны (любая другая папка). Соответственно, без внесения своих изменений непосредственно во фреймворк, единственное, что можно сделать - это переносить нужные файлы из невидимой папки в web путем подключения их как ресурса (Asset). Что в итоге все равно соберет (продублирует) все файлы в папку web. Так что, это бессмысленно.

Comment: спасибо! буду разбираться